# HTML tables - dynamic coulmn count with JS - fixed layout with wildcard - column disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

... and sorry for my English

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/S5uqc/7/) of my page. I have a table with fixed layout, 100% width and one column "be as wide as possible". Button is adding columns. When I stretching page width, everything works fine. But when I add column and stretch result area to smaller width, column "2" getting smaller and smaller to zero. Can I fix this?

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="short">1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th class="long">3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
    <td>dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    min-width:200px;
}

td,th{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.short{
    width: 50px;
}

.long{
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#addCol').click(function(){
        var c = $("table thead th").length;
        $("table thead tr").append("<th class=\"long\">" + (c+1) + "</th>");
        $("table tr:gt(0)").append("<td>dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy </td>");
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser is the column disappearing on?  I don't see the problem in the jsFiddle on Chrome.

Comment: Chrome beta. I didn't explain it good. This column is stretching to zero width, when you making width of result area smaller.

Answer (score 0):

For table cells the min-width is undefined. This leaves you with two option:

1. Calculate the cell widths each time you add a column. When there are too many columns, this is the time to add a width property to the second column.
2. make the second column the last one. the last column fills the rest of the table if the combined widths is smaller than the table's width, even if this column has a width attribute.

Comment: AD 1: So, this is not possible to leave second column dynamic? AD2: No, not my option. Real table is more complicated... :(

Comment: @Ajax in my opinion, it is not possible to achieve what you are asking without javascript

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that? For example, I don't know how to calculate real width of column, jQuery .width() gives me CSS value, not real value.

Comment: try jQuery's .outerWidth()

Answer (score 0):

Update you css section to this and check, using % for setting width is best way to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S5uqc/12/).

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

td,th{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
.short{
    width: 50%;
}

.long{
    width: 150%;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not good solution, because it is customer's wish to have few columns fixed and one adapting...

Comment: just give inline styles for the columns that you wish to have fixed width.